# Como funciona paginação por Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou utilizando um `script` para fazer a paginação através de `Ajax`, que funciona de forma `assíncrona`, a situação me deixou curioso, porque até então eu só havia utilizado paginação `php+mysql`, nunca `php+mysql+ajax`.

Se meu banco tiver `30 registros` e eu só mostrar `10` por página com `Ajax`, o que acontecem com os outros `20`? Eles são carregados?

Comment: Depende de como o seu PHP foi codificado. Na realidade o AJAX no conceito nao é diferente do que o normal, pois para cada solicitação do ajax, voce vai ao servidor e este provê um retorno para você. 

O Php que voce chama no ajax que vai fazer a consulta, e vai depender de como voce monta a consulta no servidor que definirá a quantidade de registros que será buscada...

Geralmente como um bom *approach* trazemos apenas os registros da pagina solicitada.

Comment: Tá, então vamos imaginar que no SELECT com PHP eu não use o LIMIT X, e que existam 200 registros em minha tabela. Quando a página for carregada, os 200 serão buscados no banco? O AJAX limita essa busca ou ele só exibe os 10? Porque não adiantaria nada eu querer limitar a busca sendo que os 200 registros são carregados, mas não são exibidos. Pensando melhor, eu devo fazer que a cada página que o usuario navegue a query SELECT deve ser executada e buscar 1-10, depois 11,21, 22-32 ?

Comment: Primeiro precisamos saber quando utilizar o termo AJAX. AJAX é uma solicitação pura e simplesmente.

Quando voce usa a frase "O AJAX limita essa busca" na realidade está bem equivocada, pois não é o AJAX quem limita e sim a função PHP que foi chamada pelo AJAX.

Comment: E como eu faço para que o limite dado para a query em PHP seja o mesmo para a solicitação dada ao AJAX, para que cada página se encarregue de solicitar +10, porque se não isso causaria um estrago no trafego, não é? Imagine uma pessoa que acessaria o site através de dados móveis..